# Did Rand Paul publicly approve of Obama's withdrawal from Iraq?

Tags: united-states, republican-party, iraq

Rand Paul is one of the few (I think) high-level Republicans who [publically approved](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/opinion/2019/10/16/donald-trump-right-leave-syria-rand-paul-editorials-debates/4003497002/) of Trump's decision to withdraw from Syria. (Even Mitch McConnell [attacked it](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2019/oct/19/donald-trump-mitch-mcconnell-syria-impeachment) and reminded that "A bipartisan supermajority of 70 senators supported an amendment I wrote [which] stated our opposition to prematurely exiting Syria or Afghanistan.")

**Has Rand Paul publically approved of Obama's decision to withdraw from Iraq though?** (Some Republicans now blame Obama for the rise of Isis that followed that withdrawal. Or at least [Trump did](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-election-trump/trump-calls-obama-clinton-islamic-state-co-founders-draws-rebuke-idUSKCN10M146) and more predictably so did [Cheney](https://www.wsj.com/articles/dick-cheney-and-liz-cheney-the-collapsing-obama-doctrine-1403046522).) According to Wikipedia's bio of Paul, which unfortunately cites an (now) inaccessible article on this, in 2010 Paul

> supported the war in Afghanistan and opposed rapid withdrawal from Iraq.

But of course, something have changed by the time (2011) when Obama [decided to withdraw from Iraq](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yen-Um6RmPs), including Paul's position. So, has Paul made any public statements on Obama's decision to withdraw from Iraq?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct approval of Obama's withdrawal decision, but [in 2014](https://www.nbcnews.com/storyline/iraq-turmoil/rand-paul-i-dont-blame-obama-iraq-turmoil-n136846) Paul blamed the Iraq War more than Obama for Isis:

> “What’s going on now -- I don’t blame on President Obama,” Paul said in an interview with NBC’s David Gregory to air on “Meet the Press” Sunday. “Has he really got the solution? Maybe there is no solution. But I do blame the Iraq War on the chaos that is in the Middle East.” [...] ”Was the war won in 2005, when many of these people said it was won? They didn’t really, I think, understand the civil war that would break out.”

If Paul made a more direct statement on Obama's withdrawal decision being right or wrong (he's rather equivocal in what I quoted above), I'll accept that answer instead.